# How can I reset my local branch to track remote branch

Tags: git

I am setting my local branch to track remote branch like this:

```
$ git branch --set-upstream foo upstream/foo
```

But when I do git status, I get:

```
$ git status
# On branch foo
# Your branch and 'upstream/foo' have diverged,
# and have 108 and 43 different commits each, respectively.
```

What can I do to fix my local branch so that it no longer diverged with remote branch?
One idea I have is to delete my local branch and recreate another branch to track the same remote branch. Is there another way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two divergent lines of development.  You have two choices:

- Abandon some of your changes, or
- Merge the two sets of changes

The first option is easy.  Deleting your local branch and then checkout out a new local copy of the remote branch will accomplish this.  You could also:

```
git reset --hard upstream/foo
```

The second option may require you to manually correct merge conflicts.  In theory, simply running:

```
git pull
```

Should perform the merge, leaving you to clean up any conflicts.

Comment: Keep in mind that `git pull` could be set to do a rebase instead of a merge!